# Sharing control instance within a view in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

I'm having some issues with the wpf tab control. Not sure the title of the question is right I will refine it accoring to answers.

I want to create a simple panel system. I want to inject ot my "panel viewModel" 2 view model

- MainViewModel will be display as the main area
- PanelViewModel will be display as a panel on the right hand side of the view

the panelViewModel will be hidden by default and a button will display it on top of the main view model when needed

The view look like this:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
 <DataTemplate x:Key="MainWindowTemplate" DataType="{x:Type UserControl}">
  <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding DataContext.MainViewModel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" />
 </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid>

 <Grid Visibility="{Binding IsPanelHidden, Converter={StaticResource bool2VisibilityConverter}}">
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

  <ContentControl Grid.Column="0" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource MainWindowTemplate}" />

  <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding PanelTitle}" Command="{Binding Path=ShowPanelCommand}">
    <Button.LayoutTransform>
      <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
    </Button.LayoutTransform>
  </Button>
 </Grid>

<Grid Visibility="{Binding IsPanelHidden, Converter={StaticResource revertBool2VisibilityConverter}}">

  <ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource MainWindowTemplate}" />

  <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Border Grid.Column="2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Red" >
      <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
          <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Border HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
          <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding PanelTitle}" Margin="5,5,0,2" HorizontalAlignment="Left"></TextBlock>
            <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,5,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" >
              <Button Content="Minimze" Command="{Binding HidePanelCommand}"/>
            </StackPanel>
          </Grid>
        </Border>

        <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1" Margin="2" Content="{Binding PanelViewModel}" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
      </Grid>
    </Border>
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

The view model look like that:

```
public class TestTabViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    #region private attributes

    #endregion

    public TestTabViewModel(string panelName, object panelViewModel, object mainViewModel)
    {
        IsPanelHidden = true;
        PanelTitle = panelName;
        PanelViewModel = panelViewModel;
        MainViewModel = mainViewModel;
        ShowPanelCommand = new DelegateCommand(() =>ManagePanelVisibility(true));
        HidePanelCommand = new DelegateCommand(() => ManagePanelVisibility(false));
    }

    #region properties


    public string PanelTitle { get; private set; }

    public bool IsPanelHidden { get; private set; }

    public object PanelViewModel { get; private set; }

    public object MainViewModel { get; private set; }

    public DelegateCommand ShowPanelCommand { get; private set; }

    public DelegateCommand HidePanelCommand { get; private set; }

    #endregion

    #region private methods

    private void ManagePanelVisibility(bool visible)
    {
        IsPanelHidden = !visible;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => IsPanelHidden);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

So for so good, this system work fine I aslo added some pin command but I remove them from here to make it "simple".

My problem come when the main view model hold a tab control. In this, case if I select a tab and "open" the panel, the tab selected is "changed". In fact it's not changed it's just that I display another contentControl which is not synchronize with the previouse one. I guess that the view instance is not the same even if the viewmodel behind is.

So how do I share a view  instance within a view (or have the selection process synchornized)? My first guest was to use the datatemplate (as show in the example) but it did not solve my problem.

By the way, I know some third-party handling panel docking pin ... (eg avalon) but all the one I found are really too much for my simple need.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet would probably be to replace your two Grids with a single `ContentControl`, and switch the `Template` on button click or in a Trigger. This way your actual Content (the `TabControl`) will be the same, but the template used to display the Content will change

Here's a quick example:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="Grid1Template" TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
        <DockPanel>
            <Grid Background="CornflowerBlue" Width="100" DockPanel.Dock="Left" />
            <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
        </DockPanel>
    </ControlTemplate>

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="Grid2Template" TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
        <DockPanel>
            <Grid Background="CornflowerBlue" Width="100" DockPanel.Dock="Right" />
            <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
        </DockPanel>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<DockPanel>
    <ToggleButton x:Name="btnToggle" Content="Toggle View" DockPanel.Dock="Top" />
    <ContentControl>
        <ContentControl.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource Grid1Template}" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=btnToggle, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource Grid2Template}" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ContentControl.Style>

        <TabControl>
            <TabItem Header="Tab1" />
            <TabItem Header="Tab2" />
            <TabItem Header="Tab3" />
        </TabControl>
    </ContentControl>

</DockPanel>
```

Comment: The problem is that the MainWindowTemplate is included in both grids. in the first one the MainWindowTemplate is on the left side of the grid with the command on the right side and the second grid the MainWindowTemplate is scretch on the all view and the commands go over it on the right. The aim of the grids is to change the position of the mainWindowTemplate but I don't want to work on a different instance (want the mainwindowtemplate tab selection or text focus to remain the same whatever the grid positioning displayed

Comment: @gbr That is why you replace the `Template`. All WPF controls are actually "lookless", meaning the way they are drawn on the screen isn't part of the control. You can define your own way to draw the control by replacing the Template with one of your own. I updated my answer with a working example which switches the `Template` of a `ContentControl` based on a Trigger. You'll notice that the same TabControl is used, so the selected tab stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

i dont know if i get what you want but i think that you could do the following.

i assume that you want some "MainViewmodeldata" be presented as your tabcontrol.
so i woulf first create a datatemplate for this.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
 <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type MainViewmodeldata}">
  <TabControl>
   <TabItem Header="Tab1">
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="Tab1Content"/>
    </TabItem>
   <TabItem Header="Tab2">
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="Tab2Content"/>
   </TabItem>
  </TabControl>
 </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

now i would just bind my this mainviewmodeldata to the contentcontrol and let wpf render it for you. i really dont know if you still need these two grids, cause i dont know what you wanna achieve.

```
 <Grid x:Name="Grid1" Visibility="{Binding IsPanelHidden, Converter={StaticResource bool2VisibilityConverter}}">
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

  <ContentControl Content="{Binding MainViewmodelData}" />

  <StackPanel  Grid.Column="1">
    <Button x:Name="Button1" Content="Switch look" Command="{Binding ShowPanelCommand}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Look1"/>
  </StackPanel>
 </Grid>

<Grid x:Name="Grid2" Visibility="{Binding IsPanelHidden, Converter={StaticResource revertBool2VisibilityConverter}}">
  <ContentControl Content="{Binding MainViewmodelData}" />
  <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right">
    <Button x:Name="Button2" Content="Switch look" Command="{Binding HidePanelCommand}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Look2"/>
  </StackPanel>
 </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: In fact my MainWindowTemplate what you called MainViewmodelData is a view/viewmodel, this view contain a tab control. I'm nearly sure the problem come from the fact that I add 2 contentControl in my view and the visual aspect of each contentControl are handled individually (i want them synchornize). I need do the 2 grid stuff because I want to create a side panel with pin and overlap behavior. everything work so foar except for this behavior. I could use some third party (like avalon) but what i found is not light and easy enough to suite my needs.

Comment: your MainWindowTemplate is for typeof Usercontrol, my DataTemplate is for typeof your viewmodel. can you post your viewmodel code?

Comment: I edited the question to reflect in more detail my context hope it help you